# Sharepoint 3 state workflow sending notification twice, on Add new Item event?

Tags: workflow

I have share point list which receives the values from asp.net page (using Web services) on the list I have created an 3 state Workflow (By choosing List -> Workflow setting -> configure to run on ITEM, from the top ribbon in the browser) choosing (Start this workflow when a new item is created.)  and in "Specify what you want to happen when a workflow is initiated:" I have checked "Send e-mail message", rest everything is disabled.

Everything work fine, just that it send the notification mail twice, which is confusing the stockholder with single to 2 records insertion.

I tried many options but no luck so far.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting the workflow to pause for 1 minute before it sends the e-mail? I don't know much about your specific example but I had a Designer e-mail that would send twice but by adding a pause, it only sent once.